# what is this function doing

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I'm new to functions and was wondering if someone can tell me what this function is doing? It is converting '8/20/20118' to 0.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ISDATE(v_date IN VARCHAR2) RETURN number IS
    v_date1 DATE;
BEGIN
    select to_date(v_date,'mm/dd/yyyy') into v_date1 from dual;
        RETURN 1;
    Exception WHEN Others THEN
        RETURN 0;
END;
```

I don’t get this part.

**ISDATE(v_date IN VARCHAR2) RETURN number IS
    v_date1 DATE**

Comment: That is the function definition.  What don't you understand?

Comment: 20118 is quite a strange year...

Comment: @Aleksej - that's why it throws an exception and returns zero *8-)

Comment: So is it actually checking the isdate function even though it is in oracle?

Comment: The structure of a function [is explained in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/CREATE-FUNCTION-statement.html). What exactly is it that you don't get? Your example is fairly simple and doesn't use any obscure syntax or tricks?

Comment: Thanks alex. this part I don't get. sorry totally new to functions, ISDATE(v_date IN VARCHAR2) RETURN number IS v_date1 DATE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION              -- You are creating or replacing a function in the
                                        -- database
ISDATE                                  -- The name of the function is "ISDATE"
(
  v_date IN VARCHAR2                    -- The function takes one argument called "v_date"
                                        -- which is an IN(put) parameter of the VARCHAR2
                                        -- (string) data type
)
RETURN number                           -- The function returns a number
IS
  v_date1 DATE;                         -- The function has one local variable "v_date1"
                                        -- which is of the DATE data type.
BEGIN                                   -- The start of the main body of the function
  select to_date(v_date,'mm/dd/yyyy')   -- Try to convert the v_date argument to a date
                                        -- using the mm/dd/yyyy format model
  into v_date1                          -- and put the result into the v_date1 variable
  from dual;                            -- Using the DUAL table supplied by Oracle.
  RETURN 1;                             -- If successful then return 1
Exception                               -- If there was an error then...
  WHEN Others THEN                      --   When the error was not matched by another rule
    RETURN 0;                           --     return 0
END;                                    -- End the function.
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does that function work but CASE WHEN to_char('8/20/20118') = TO_DATE('8/20/20118','MM/DD/YYYY') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TTTTT not work?

Comment: @smattiko84 Because `TO_DATE` throws an exception when the format model does not match the date string and the PL/SQL function has an exception handling block that will catch it but the SQL statement does not. There are other issues as well around implicit data type conversions with `TO_CHAR` but that is getting too complicated for replying in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It's checking if the input string can be converted to date using the specified format and returns 1 or no if it can or cannot, respectively.

Comment: So what does ISDATE(v_date IN VARCHAR2) RETURN number IS
    v_date1 DATE do?

Comment: @smattiko84 that is the parameter declaration and the return value

Answer (score 1):

As explained [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/CREATE-FUNCTION-statement.html):

- `ISDATE` is the function name.
- `(v_date IN VARCHAR2)` is the parameter declaration; in this case there is a single input (`IN`, indicating it is read-only within the function) argument which excpects a string value; that parameter is called `v_date` so you use that name to refer to the passed-in value within the function body.
- `RETURN number` says that the function returns a value that is a `number`
- `IS` indicates that you've moved finished the parameter/return declaration and are moving on to the optional local variable declaration and the function body.
- `v_date1 DATE` is declaring a local variable of type `date`, called `v_date1`.

Comment: Thanks. Why does that function work but CASE WHEN to_char('8/20/20118') = TO_DATE('8/20/20118','MM/DD/YYYY') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TTTTT not work?

Comment: @smattiko84 - because of the function's exception handler. In your statement, `to_char('8/20/20118')` is converting a string to a string, which is pointless. `TO_DATE('8/20/20118','MM/DD/YYYY')` will throw ORA-01830, before there is a chance to evaluate the case expression. (And if you used a valid date, you'd have to do implicit conversion to compare the values anyway, so it wouldn't tell you much really.)

Comment: Thank you. What is an exception handler?

Comment: The `exception when others ...` part. (Using `when others` is usually a bad idea, because it often accidentally hides issues. It's just about OK here... but don't get into the habit of including it everywhere.)